# Stop HTML Tidy in sublime from adding extra tags

Tags: sublimetext2, htmltidy

How do you prevent HTML tidy in Sublime text to from adding extra tags such as this

This is what I want

```
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="span4">
            <section>
            <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
            </section>
            <section>
            <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
            </section>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

After using HTML tidy I get this -- which I dont want

```
      <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="row">
                <aside class="span4">          
    <section>
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
    </section>

    <section>
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
    </section>

    </aside>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you looking for "Reindent lines"?

Comment: Yes Thank you!!! Can you post that so I can close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"HTML Tidy" isn't for what you're trying to do.

For what you're doing, the "Reindent lines" feature of sublime text 2 should be sufficient.